# OCaml / Camlp4 - renaming polymorphic variants

Tags: syntax, ocaml, camlp4

Is there a way to have all polymorphic variants in an OCaml program renamed to maximum two characters each at preprocessing time, of course preserving their uniqueness? The renaming should be consistent for all program modules too.

Can someone sketch out a solution using Camlp4 + Hashtable or similar?

Comment: You can use CamlP4's AST mapper and there is a tutorial of it: https://github.com/ocaml/camlp4/wiki/Pa_float .  If I were you, however, I would use PPX and Ast_mapper of compiler-libs instead of CamlP4.

Comment: Ok, time to learn PPX....

Comment: Why would you want to do that? At compile time polymorphic variant names are mapped to a hash of the string so at runtime the length of the variant name doesn't matter. All you achieve is to obfuscate the code and make error messages meaningless.

Comment: Hi Goswin, I needed that for porting reasons. I was writing a bytecode interpreter for a 16 bit architecture which couldn't manage such long hashes.